# Looking for opens source log aggregator

Tags: linux, ssh, logs, open-source

I am looking for open source log aggregator. My requirements are very simple:

1. Aggregate logs from multiple machines via SSH
2. Allow free text / regex search.
3. Allow realtime view of logs on a console screen

I am looking for free on-premise solution rather than a paid tool such as [Loggly](https://www.loggly.com/) or [papertrail](https://papertrailapp.com/)

I have looked at [fluentd](http://www.fluentd.org/) , [ELK](https://www.elastic.co/webinars/introduction-elk-stack) but none of it satisfies my simple 3 requirements.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open Source Alternatives

[Graylog2](https://www.graylog.org/)

[Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash)

[Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana)

Do update the question with comments as to which one you end up using and your personal comments

Following two articles discusses the same question

http://www.infoworld.com/article/2610524/log-analysis/splunk-feels-the-heat-from-stronger--cheaper-open-source-rivals.html

http://www.slant.co/topics/326/~log-aggregation-monitoring-tools